# tweepy.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden - Issue with Twitter API authentication using Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm encountering

```
tweepy.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
When authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints, you must use keys and tokens from a Twitter developer App that is attached to a Project. You can create a project via the developer portal.
```

while trying to run the following code that fetches a user's post history using the Twitter API and Tweepy:

```
    client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=bearer_token)
    tweets = client.search_recent_tweets(query=f'from:{user_handle}')
```

My app does seem to be connected to a project (see img)
I have come across some links that suggest it might be a Twitter issue related to API authentication. However, I would like to confirm if this is indeed the case and if there are any possible solutions or workarounds for this problem.

Links indicating it might be a Twitter issue:

https://github.com/twitterdev/Twitter-API-v2-sample-code/issues/58
https://twittercommunity.com/t/when-authenticating-requests-to-the-twitter-api-v2-endpoints-you-must-use-keys-and-tokens-from-a-twitter-developer-app-that-is-attached-to-a-project-you-can-create-a-project-via-the-developer-portal/189699

I would greatly appreciate any insights, explanations, or potential solutions to resolve this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your app has the *Free* access tier which only allows:

- Posting tweets with the Twitter API v2
- Media Upload and Login With Twitter with the Twitter API v1.1

To do anything else, you need at least the *Basic* access tier, which costs some money.

The access tiers are documented in https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api

And of course you should use a recent version of Tweepy that supports the V2 API.

Comment: ok, i understand now why my code is not working, this is extremely SAD for that platform tbh ! Thanks elon.