# Forbidden 403 Error When Accessing Twitter Timeline using Tweepy v2

Tags: python, twitter, oauth, tweepy

I am encountering a "Forbidden 403" error while attempting to access my Twitter timeline using Tweepy v2. Below is the relevant portion of my code:

```
import tweepy
import keys_test as keys

# ... (other imports and variable assignments)

client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token, api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(keys.api_key, keys.api_secret, keys.access_token, keys.access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
status = client.get_home_timeline()

for stat in status:
    print(stat)
```

The error message I am receiving is as follows:

```
Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
When authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints, you must use keys and tokens from a Twitter developer App that is attached to a Project. You can create a project via the developer portal.
```

I have tried using both the client and api objects from Tweepy, but I am still encountering this issue. My keys and tokens are correctly imported from a separate file. I have also double-checked that my Twitter developer App is properly configured and attached to a Project.

Could someone please provide guidance on how to resolve this "Forbidden 403" error when accessing the Twitter timeline using Tweepy v2? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tweepy.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden - Issue with Twitter API authentication using Tweepy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76518869/tweepy-errors-forbidden-403-forbidden-issue-with-twitter-api-authentication-u)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pay for to have access to the api endpoint, check this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76520660/18812499